# POST request returns 400 Bad Request API error in Spring Boot and Postman

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, postman, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot application with a MlStatisticsController class that contains three API endpoints: one for adding , another for retrieving all statistics, and a third one for finding statistics by their Id. The get  endpoints are working correctly, but I'm facing an issue with the addStatistics endpoint.

When I try to make a POST request to the addStatistics endpoint using Postman, I receive a 400 Bad Request API error. I've checked the request body, the Content-Type header, and the URL, but I can't seem to find the cause of the error.

Here is a snippet of my MlStatisticsController class:

```
@RestController

public class MlStatisticsController {

    //Inject service
    @Autowired
    private MlStatisticsService mlStatisticsService;

    @PostMapping("/addStatistics")
    public MlStatistics addStatistics(@RequestBody MlStatistics mlStatistics){
        return mlStatisticsService.saveMlStatistics(mlStatistics);
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class MlStatisticsService {

    //Inject Repository
    @Autowired
    private MlStatisticsRepo mlStatisticsRepo;

    public MlStatistics saveMlStatistics(MlStatistics mlStatistics){
        return mlStatisticsRepo.save(mlStatistics);
    }
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface MlStatisticsRepo extends JpaRepository <MlStatistics, Integer> {

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class MlStatistics {

    public MlStatistics(){

    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String creationDate;
    private String configId;
    private String executionType;
    private Double accuracy;
    private Double precisions;

    public MlStatistics(int id, String creationDate, String configId, String executionType, Double accuracy, Double precisions) {
        this.id = id;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.configId = configId;
        this.executionType = executionType;
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
        this.precisions = precisions;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getConfigId() {
        return configId;
    }

    public void setConfigId(String configId) {
        this.configId = configId;
    }

    public String getExecutionType() {
        return executionType;
    }

    public void setExecutionType(String executionType) {
        this.executionType = executionType;
    }

    public Double getAccuracy() {
        return accuracy;
    }

    public void setAccuracy(Double accuracy) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
    }

    public Double getPrecisions() {
        return precisions;
    }

    public void setPrecisions(Double precisions) {
        this.precisions = precisions;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MlStatistics{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", creationDate='" + creationDate + '\'' +
                ", configId='" + configId + '\'' +
                ", executionType='" + executionType + '\'' +
                ", accuracy=" + accuracy +
                ", precisions=" + precisions +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I'm using Postman to send the POST request, and I've set the Content-Type header to application/json. The request body is a JSON object representing the MlStatistics entity, which should match the structure of the MlStatistics class.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what could be causing the 400 Bad Request error and how to resolve it. If there are any other parts of the code or configurations that I should check, please let me know. Thank you!

```
{
"creationDate":"Now",
"configId":"acsa", 
"executionType":"ascasc",
"accuracy":81.1,
"precisions":10.1
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM52a.png)

Comment: remove `id` field from request and retry again please

Comment: i have tried that also. Getting same error

Comment: to double fields set value with `.` something like it `81.2`

Comment: also add annotation to entity class `@Table(tableName)`

Comment: @AndreiLisa I tried, still getting same error

Comment: and change your `id` field from `int` to object wrapper `Integer`

Comment: I have done all the above changes.. still getting same error

Comment: Update your question with screen of postman window,  where i can see request body, url and response.

Comment: make sure you select application/json as request body in postman

Comment: Yep, i have done exactly that, please checkout the image added at the last

Comment: Is there any logs in the spring console? If yes , can you post image or the text?

Comment: no errors or warnings in the logs

Comment: add `@RequestMapping("/end")` at controller class level annotation and after your request will look so `/end/addStatistics`

Comment: I'll create a project with your class and let you know

Comment: I copied your Entity and controller and hit the request with postman. I got 200 from postman and was able to log the payload as well

Comment: Looks like issue with my project ?

Comment: Maybe some configuration related , I can post an answer with all the required stuff

Answer (score 0):

I have created a seperate project with some enhancements ,

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dev-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Dev-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8890


spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Dev2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: <username>
    password: <password>
```

My model:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MlStatistics {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String creationDate;
    private String configId;
    private String executionType;
    private Double accuracy;
    private Double precisions;

}
```

Project Structure

```
Dev-2:
    --> com.example.Dev2
        --> Dev2Application
        --> MlStatistics
        --> MlStatisticsController
        --> MlStatisticsRepo
        --> MlStatisticsService
```

Postman screenshot after hitting the request:

[image: Postman]

Console screenshot after hitting the request:

[image: Spring-console]